# Switch between nav-tabs on the successful submission of the form

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 nav-tabs , one of them shows the list of available items and the other tab gives a form where you can add the item details.

All the item details gets saved in database of submission of the form. If there is error the form submission fails and we send out 500 error code.

Now the problem is when i submit the form and the details are saved in database successfully i want to change the tab from Create to Edit.

Can anyone please tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: any code to look at?